# Match all files, except ones with specific extensions

Tags: npm, wildcard, glob, minmatch

How can I fix `./src/js/**/!(*.spec.js|*.test.js)`, so it doesn't return directories? I've tried it like this `./src/js/**/*.!(spec.js|test.js)`, but it matches all files except the directories, the same as `./src/js/**/*`. Example output of `./src/js/**/!(*.spec.js|*.test.js)`:

```
[ './src/js/__tests__',
  './src/js/__tests__/example.js',
  './src/js/example.js',
  './src/js/index.js' ]
```

Desired output:

```
[ './src/js/__tests__/example.js',
  './src/js/example.js',
  './src/js/index.js' ]
```

[glob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob) version 7.1.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you want to exclude folders in your case, which can be done by adding `(^/)` at the end.

The complete glob should be `./src/js/**/!(*.spec.js|*.test.js|^/)`

You can verify the micromatch syntax [here](https://github.com/micromatch/micromatch)

UPDATE:

With the npm module glob there is an option which is called `nodir`. If it is set to true, there wont be any directory paths in the output.

Example:

```
var glob = require("glob")

glob("./src/js/**/!(*.spec.js|*.test.js)", { nodir: true }, (er, files) => {
  console.log(er, files)
})
```

You can find more information on all available options [in their section about options.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob#options)

Comment: I didn't clarify enough, the wildcard that I've posted returns the needed files, but it also includes any directory that it finds, I need to make it return just the files.

Comment: Ah it does make more sense with this clarification. Basically you want to exclude folders in your case, which can be done by adding `(^/)` at the end. The complete glob should be `./src/js/**/!(*.spec.js|*.test.js)(^/)`

Comment: When I execute this I get an empty array.

Comment: Ah if you are using the module glob, you can just set the nodir option to true. I will add an example to the answer.